# is it possible to change layout content in laravel through ajax request?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-4, laravel-blade

This the controller file, which setup layout of view.

```
class DashboardController extends BaseController{

    public  function __construct(){
        $this->layout='expert-dashboard::layouts.default';
    }

    public function index(){
        $action=Input::get('action');
        if($action=="dashboard"){
            $this->layout->content=View::make(Config::get('expert-dashboard::dashboard'));
            return ;

        }else{
            $this->layout->content=View::make(Config::get('expert-dashboard::activity'));
            return;

        }

    }
}
```

The js code which calls the action to replace with different content dynamically.The result shows, the the layout content has changed but not rendered. what will be the cause,else how to render the change.

```
$scope.changeContent=function(){
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: './dashboard',
            params:{
                "action":"dashboard"
            },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

        }).
            success(function(response) {

            }).
            error(function(response) {
            });
    };
```

Comment: You need to return the contact from Laravel to your jquery function - then have jQuery update the DOM element

Comment: Of course i know to update DOM element via jquery/javascript , but the thing i discussed here is, is it possible to update the view via controller in laravel.